# How to see Attunity drivers MSORA as a provider for SQL Linked Server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis, linked-server, attunity

I want to see the MSORA driver for Attunity Oracle SSIS 1.2 drivers for SQL Server 2008.  I have installed the x64 drivers, and installed the VC++ Redistributable Runtime before hand (as this seems to prevent some errors during installation)....But I cant see MSORA as a provider in SQL Management Studio.  I have tried to manually RegSvr32 the .dll file, and restart the server - but cant see it in the provider list.

What do I have to do to see the provider in the list so I can create a linked server from the Attunity drivers.

Any advice appreciated.

i

Comment: Are you referring to the [Microsoft Connector v1.2 for Oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29284)? It appears to be only for use in SSIS and has nothing to do with linked servers. Usually you use an Oracle OLE DB provider or ODBC driver to create a linked server. But your question isn't clear about exactly what your goal is: are you just trying to create a linked server to Oracle?

Comment: Hi -I have a linked server to Oracle using native Oracle driver. I just want to see if I can use an attunity driver for a linked server so I can compare performance.  Yes, Oracle 1.2 drivers for SSIS.

Comment: >> But I cant see MSORA as a provider in SQL Management Studio

Where do you expect to 'see' them? Are you running a command that is failing?

Comment: Server Objects ->Linked Servers ->Providers.  When setting up a linked server you can only select from the providers listed here, which seem to be the providers installed locally on the SQL box.  I know attunity drivers are installed as I can deploy SSIS packages to the box and run them (having overcome missing MSORA type messages)...but cant see MSORA as an installed provider.